# Pypika: Is it possible to dynamically change the operator in where clause

Tags: python, sql, pypika

I am using Pypika to query a HDB. Usually I create the query and then add where clauses like this:

```
query = query.where(table.ID == value)
```

Now I have a situation where I don't know which operator will be used. It can be any of the possible operators:

```
['==', '<>', '<', '>', '<=', '>=']
```

Is there a way to specify the operator for Pypika dynamically?

At the moment I am doing this:

```
if operator == '<=':
        query = query.where(table.ID == value)
elif operator == '>=':
    ...
```

But I would like to do something like this:

```
operator = '=='
query = query.where(table.ID {operator} value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that you posted this about 30 days ago, so I hope you have found a solution in the meantime. But, if you haven't - I ran into the same issue, and the following worked for me: writing a function that takes an operator from the `operator` module, and produces the query:

```
from pypika import Table, Field, Query
from typing import List, Callable
import operator


def gen_my_query(varname: str, 
             my_operator: Callable, 
             permitted_value: int, 
             my_table: str, 
             selected_vars: List[str]):

    my_query = Query.from_(Table(my_table)
                          ).select(','.join(selected_vars)
                          ).where(
                                  my_operator(Field(varname), permitted_value)
                          ).get_sql(quote_char=None)

    return my_query
```

The function can be used as follows:

```
gen_my_query(varname='id', 
             my_operator=operator.eq, 
             permitted_value=1, 
             my_table='table', 
             selected_vars=["var1", "var2", "var3"])
```

Which produces the following result:

```
'SELECT var1,var2,var3 FROM table WHERE id=1'
```

If you want to continue using the operators defined as strings, you could e.g. define a mapping in a dictionary and refactor the function above to grab the correct operator from the dict, e.g.:

```
my_operators = {'==': operator.eq,
                '<': operator.le} # ... etc.
```

Hope this helps!